# Firebase setPersistenceEnabled(true) is not working for me, developing application in dart?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

We are developing an app in dart where in we want to store data locally so that when app restarts, user will be able to see data even if there is no connectivity. I have read about setPersistenceEnabled property to do that but I think we are doing something wrong. Please find the below details - can someone please help us.

Running an app on android emulator Nexus 5

We have connected app with Firebase database for android version.

Included Firebase_database and Firebase_core packages in pubspec.yaml

Below is the code where we call setPersistenceEnabled method in main.dart - Stateful widget is being used.

Also when fetching data for specific collection we are using REST API.

Let me know if we are doing something wrong or require more details.

I have connected_products.dart file wherein i have created this function to call instance of database.

```
 FirebaseDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    if (database == null) {
      print("should fire once");
      database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
      database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
      database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(25000000); //25 MB
    }
    return database;
  }
```

In the same file down below i have a function to fetch products

```
Future<Null> fetchProducts() {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    return getDatabaseInstance()
        .reference()
        .child("products")
        .once()
        .then<Null>((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      final List<Product> fetchedProductList = [];
      snapshot.value.forEach((dynamic productData) {
        final Product product = Product(
            blockno: productData['BLOCK_NO'],
            name: productData['NAME'],
            id: productData['CARD_NO'].toString().isEmpty
                ? 'Not Available'
                : productData['CARD_NO'],
            serialno: productData['SR_NO'],
            surname: productData['SURNAME'],
            firstname: productData['FIRSTNAME'], // This is modified fo search
            age: productData['AGE'],
            gender: productData['GENDER'],
            acnumber: productData['AC_NO'],
            isDone: productData['IsDone']);
        fetchedProductList.add(product);
      });
      _products = fetchedProductList;

      _isLoading = false;
      _isFetchCalled = true;
      notifyListeners();
      _selProductIndex = null;
    }).catchError((error) {
      _isLoading = false;
      print(error);
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    });
  }
```

I have another file called phone.dart - where I call this function

```
@override
  initState() {
    if (widget.model.getFetchCalled == false) {
      widget.model.fetchProducts();
      widget.model.checkToSeeString();
    }
    widget.model.fetchPhone();
    super.initState();
  }
```

So when i am running build i am getting below response in log.  So not sure whether data is getting cached or not since when i am closing and opening app again and i am not able to see data and had to make database call by access phone widget( internet connection is on but database call will not happen until i access phone.dart widget):

Do i need to read data from local storage explicitly ? if yes how to do that

Log Details

```
Background concurrent copying GC freed 920803(35MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 121MB/127MB, paused 1.904ms total 3.032s
W/ample.first_ap( 5637): JNI critical lock held for 16.668ms on Thread[1,tid=5637,Runnable,Thread*=0xe9f5c000,peer=0x756f0760,"main"]
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 930100(35MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 123MB/129MB, paused 22.580ms total 3.628s
W/ample.first_ap( 5637): JNI critical lock held for 19.275ms on Thread[1,tid=5637,Runnable,Thread*=0xe9f5c000,peer=0x756f0760,"main"]
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 928850(35MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 130MB/136MB, paused 4.890ms total 2.929s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1427703(38MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(7MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 161MB/167MB, paused 1.943ms total 2.252s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2657600(56MB) AllocSpace objects, 498(23MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 229MB/235MB, paused 1.617ms total 3.073s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2324689(78MB) AllocSpace objects, 1485(69MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 213MB/219MB, paused 1.554ms total 2.347s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2098267(69MB) AllocSpace objects, 1313(61MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 239MB/245MB, paused 1.858ms total 4.004s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 14.705s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 5390417(114MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(42MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 226MB/232MB, paused 1.479ms total 2.502s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ProfileSaver for 78.480ms
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2346436(77MB) AllocSpace objects, 1451(67MB) LOS objects, 2% free, 218MB/224MB, paused 1.214ms total 1.639s
I/ample.first_ap( 5637): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2119192(71MB) AllocSpace objects, 1400(65MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 129MB/135MB, paused 1.393ms total 2.332s
```

Comment: What makes you think the `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` isn't working?

Comment: Hi Frank- I have tried running app on emulator, data got fetched in app using REST API and then i closed it. Later when i started app again data was not there and had to make database call again to fetch the data.

Comment: We'd have to see the code of how you retrieve the data, but given your mention of REST API it seems that you're retrieving the data outside of the SDK, which means that the SDK can't cache the data for you.

Comment: Let me paste the code in sometime but meanwhile while fetching the data from database collection i am using i.e "http.get(databaseURL/colletion.json)". Is this might be the reason ? do i need to replace it with database().reference.child('collection-name') ??

Comment: You enable persistence on the Firebase client with `database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`. Only data that you're reading via that client will be persisted by that client. If you're not using that same client to read the data, that data won't be persisted by that client.

Comment: @NeerajKaple `database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);` returns a `Future`, you might want to check if it successfully resolves or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment thread it seems that you're not retrieving the data through the client that you enable persistence on, but you're reading data through the REST API.

Since you enable persistence on the Firebase client with `database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, only data that you're reading via that client will be persisted. If you're using a different client (or even a different API) to read the data, that data won't be persisted by that client.

Comment: Thanks Frank ! Let me try that!

Comment: Frank - Can you please take a look at the code and let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you moved on from using the REST API to using the SDK. That means the first cause of problems (calls to the REST API aren't cached by the client SDK) is gone. Any problems with the SDK are a different problem, and you should open a new question for them.